# How to create a modular client-side / serverside application with different codebases (the JS part)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, module, es6-modules

We are currently starting to rebuild our CMS. We have good experience with VueJS. However, it'll not become a full VueJS single page application because we can not yet get rid of server-side rendering files (JSP).

The challenage, is that the CMS is not in 1 codebase. We use approximately the following structure:

CMS basics (in separate git repository)

- Module: user management
- Module: content management
- etc.

Additional modules

- Newsletter (in separate repository)
- Forms (in separate repository)
- etc.

These are all Maven modules that we use in multiple projects for customers. We do not always use all modules. We add the modules that we do use as dependency in the Maven 'customer project' (for completeness: in the pom.xml of the project).

The project structure (in separate repository)

- Dep # 1
- Dep # 2
- Specific customer module
- etc.

Our preference for client-side / JS goes out to using VueJS components  Typescript classes (our own custom code) and of course external libraries (with node/yarn as dependency manager).

Now I have done research on ES6 imports / modules, but do not yet have the following challenge covered / tackeled:

The CMS will contain several build bundles, such as:

- generic.js (eg code for showing modals / alerts etc.) *a bundled JS file, which contains build Typescript classes / vue components etc.*
- content-manament.js (with dependence on generic.js libraries)
- etc.

The newsletter module will contain a build bundle: newsletter.js (with dependence on generic.js libraries)

The custom project will also contain modules with dependencies to classes in generic.js

Ideally, I would like to build the bundles separately. Such as:

- generic.js (built bundle - contains all the narrower libraries below)
- messages.ts
- dialogs.ts
- cms.js
- newsletter.js
- custom-customer-module.js

And in newsletter.js I'd like to use classes from generic.js such as:

```
import {messages} from "????";

messages.alert('Alert text');
```

I do not yet see how I can best tackle this problem. Perhaps I think too difficult but hope that one of you has a good starting point.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: are you using Webpack ?

Comment: @MohamedRamrami that's is an option. We are in the phase that we can still decide what we're gonna use

Answer (score 0):

You can use Webpack with [Code splitting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/)

> There are three general approaches to code splitting available:
>
> - Entry Points: Manually split code using entry configuration.
> - Prevent Duplication: Use the SplitChunksPlugin to dedupe and split chunks.
> - Dynamic Imports: Split code via inline function calls within modules.

*Assuming that the high level modules (`cms.js`, `newsletter.js`, ...) are independent from each other, and only depends on `generic.js`*

#### Folder strcuture

```
src/
├── cms/
│   ├── index.ts
│   ├── ...
├── newsletter/
│   ├── index.ts
│   ├── ...
└── generics/
    ├── index.ts
    ├── messages.ts
    ├── dialogs.ts
```

#### src/generics/dialogs.ts

```
export function open(title: string) {
    console.log('Opening dialog : ', title);
}
```

#### src/generics/messages.ts

```
export function alert(msg: string) {
    console.log('alert : ', msg);
}
```

#### src/generics/index.ts

```
import * as m from './messages';
import * as d from './dialogs';

export let messages = m ;
export let dialogs = d;
```

#### src/cms/index.ts

```
import { dialogs, messages } from '../generics';

messages.alert('CMS started ...');
```

#### src/newsletter/index.ts

```
import { dialogs, messages } from '../generics';

messages.alert('Newsletter started ...');
```

---

#### Webpack Code splitting

#### 1. Entry Points

> This is by far the easiest, and most intuitive, way to split code.
>   However, it is more manual and has some pitfalls.

So in your config file, you will have to manually declare your modules using the  `entry` object :

```
// webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: {
        'newsletter': './src/newsletter/index.ts',
        'cms': './src/cms/index.ts',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
        {
            test: /\.ts?$/,
            use: 'ts-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [ '.ts', '.js' ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: "dist/",
    }
};
```

With this config, you will have two modules in the dist folder :

```
               Asset      Size      Chunks             Chunk Names
       cms.bundle.js   4.6 KiB         cms  [emitted]  cms
newsletter.bundle.js  4.64 KiB  newsletter  [emitted]  newsletter
```

Because the `cms` and `newsletter` modules depends on the `generics` module, this module is *bundled* (copied) with them.

#### 2. Prevent Duplication with SplitChunksPlugin

Add the `optimization.splitChunks` config to the `webpack.config.js` file :

```
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all',
        minChunks: 1,
        name: 'generics',
        minSize: 10,
    }
}
```

Now the `generics` module is in it's own chunk (remember to include it in your HTML file), and the build will generate 3 files :

```
               Asset      Size      Chunks             Chunk Names
       cms.bundle.js  5.85 KiB         cms  [emitted]  cms
  generics.bundle.js  1.61 KiB    generics  [emitted]  generics
newsletter.bundle.js   5.9 KiB  newsletter  [emitted]  newsletter
```

#### 3. Dynamic Imports

Change `src/cms/index.ts` to use dynamic imports :

```
import(/* webpackChunkName: "generics" */ '../generics').then(generics => {
    console.log('Generics module loaded ...');
    generics.messages.alert('CMS started ...');
});
```

Change `src/newsletter/index.ts` to use dynamic imports :

```
import(/* webpackChunkName: "generics" */ '../generics').then(generics => {
    console.log('Generics module loaded ...');
    generics.messages.alert('Newsletter started ...');
});
```

You will also have to change some Typescript compile options (and maybe install a polyfill for `Promise`) :

```
"module": "esnext",
"lib": [
    "es2015"
]
```

Now you don't have to include the `generics` module in your HTML file. When the `import()` is executed, Webpack will fetch the `generics` module from the server and cache it.

Hope this will help you get started :)

#### Edit (response to comment) :

If the modules are in separate projects. You will use `npm` or `yarn` to manage dependencies.
For example, in the `newsletter` project's `package.json`, you will add 
`generics` as a dependency.

Now, you have to use non-relative paths for your import. So for example,  the dynamic import code will be :

```
import(/* webpackChunkName: "generics" */ 'generics').then(generics => {
    console.log('Generics module loaded ...');
    generics.messages.alert('Newsletter started ...');
});
```

If you want to bundle all your code, you could add a `main` module. This module will have dependencies to all the other modules. Then in the `index.ts` of this modules, import all the other modules. This `index.ts` should be the entry point in Webpack config.

Keep in mind, that bundling all you code base in a single file is not recomended most of the time for large single page applications, because it can easily get to >8Mb. Webpack default performance recommendation is ~250kB per file.

Comment: thanks for your extensive answer! 
I only wonder whether these options will work: generics / cms and newsletter.ts are not in the same codebase. By means of Maven the codebases are 'merged' and end in 1 application (.war which is deployed in tomcat). Or could the 'dynamic imports' option work?

Comment: Thanks: I Thought about that, but doesn't that mean that both cms.js and newsletter.js will contain the generics.js sourcode? Because ideally both the cms module and the newsletter module (separate code bases) will build there own bundle (so without generics.js but still use generics runtime). Or is that also possible?

Otherwise each project which use the cms should build the entire CMS client-side sourcecode which is time expensive to build?

Comment: Yes true. You can tell Webpack that generics will be available at runtime by using the option externals, like this : externals: ['generics'] . This way it will not be bundled.